# How to call a .NET web service with Kerberos (or NTLM) authentication from Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: web-services, plsql, kerberos, ntlm

We are calling a .NET web service from our oracle database using the sys.utl_http package. We have also tested with the sys.utl_dbws package.

This works fine when there is no security on the .NET web service. However, we would like to use sys.utl_http or sys.utl_dbws to call a .NET web service with
Kerberos or NTLM authentication.

We're currently struggling with this. Any hints on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you get it done?

I havent seen that done in PL/SQL. I guess it could be done with utl_tcp ...

If you are on Unix, have you tried a Java Callout [Oracle Examples avaliable here](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/jsp/dbwebservices.html) 
There are commercial and opensource "SPNEGO" utilities that you can use from Java, for examle see [SPNEGO SourceForge project](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/)

On windows you can use a [Oracle Database Extensions for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/dotnet/ode/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

See this page for NTLM support in a pure PL/SQL solution:

http://ora-00001.blogspot.com/2011/08/ntlm-for-plsql.html